# React Native: Removed App Permission in FB caused Login Failed: You can't use Facebook to log into this app or website

Tags: react-native, facebook-login, react-native-fbsdk

I'm using React Native 0.61.5 with react-native-fbsdk 2.0.0. Facebook app is Live and configured.

The problem is with the Facebook Login when the permission is removed, facebook cannot re-authorise the Facebook Login anymore and keep displaying error in the facebook app.

[error message with Facebook App already signed-in and try to use facebook login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65hO1.png)

Above was just one of the test case. Prior to "Removing" the app permission in Facebook, the facebook login seems to be fine.

This is the basic RN code for Facebook Login

```
<LoginButton
  onLoginFinished={
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
      } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        console.log("login is cancelled.");
      } else {
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
          (data) => {
            console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
  onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("logout.")}/>
```

Any of you have any clue or solution?

I'm expecting that the facebook login will re-authorize again but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding permissions to the `LoginButton` like this. So that login button will look for the permissions too. Let me know if facebook re autorize for you..

```
 <LoginButton
      permissions={["email", "user_friends", "public_profile"]}
      onLoginFinished={this._onFacebookLoginFinished.bind(this)}
      onLogoutFinished={this._onFacebookLogoutFinished.bind(this)}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @imjaad for your attempt to answer my question.

I've resolved this by appealing on Facebook App which the app was Lived, but it has a message that "some of the functions are being restricted".

So, even if Facebook App is Live, make sure there is nothing else / warning / error message that shows up.

I tried to create another Facebook App and it was working fine as well. So nothing wrong with the fbsdk, rn or the code itself.

It was just rare event in Facebook while the appeal is in progress, the Facebook QC made it live temporary, but the message that the app is still being restricted still appear.

So make sure your FB App is Live and there is no other error / warning message in your Facebook App Dashboard.

Good Luck!